# Prevent user from installing any applications

Tags: security, multi-user, android-device-manager, restricted-profiles, parental-control

I have Galaxy J1 smartphone with OneUI and I have to prohibit installing any applications on it. I tried disabling appropriate activity in PackageInstaller, but that can be bypassed with Factory Reset in settings. Installing any AppLock applications does not help, because then can be easily removed by just booting into "Safe Mode". Is there a way I can achieve my goal?

Comment: Disable app installation is the job of an Mobile Device Management (MDM) system. However factory reset is always possible.

Comment: What MDM system can I use at home for free (I need it for single device)?